# Android emulator SD card problem

Tags: android, android-emulator

i m inserting one video in sdcard to show the video in emulator..

but showing error:

[2010-11-24 19:21:22] Failed to push sample.mov on emulator-5554: Read-only file system

pls help me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the way you are creating your sdcard (check if you have the right permissions by doing adb shell, then ls -l on sdcard from terminal).

Also check this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/XBb1xTxIkiM)